# Excel fonts: Embedding or fallback options?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm working with making a form in Excel instead of Illustrator or InDesign, as I typically do. One of the benefits about working with Adobe (and the subsequent PDFs) is that I control the fonts 100%. This is not the case when I am required to work with an Excel file that'll be passed around.

So, is there a way to embed fonts? I'd like to embed Calibri. If not, is there a way to specify a fallback font, such as Tahoma? My thinking is along the lines of a CSS font stack; not sure if there's anything like that in Excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like Excel supports embedding fonts. Word does, so there's a workaround if you're willing to embed your Excel spreadsheet inside a Word doc.

References:

- http://www.microsofttraining.net/article-687-how-embed-fonts-in-excel.html
- http://excel.tips.net/T001969_Embedding_Fonts_in_Excel.html

If you're using Calibri, you shouldn't have to worry too much. It's the default font in Office since 2007. I even have it in Mac Office.

Hope this helps.

-- jm

Comment: We just updated from '03 in our office, so I'm a little nervous about where other offices might be :) Was looking for market share data but wasn't able to find anything. Do you know anything about fallback fonts? I guess that if the font isn't found, it would just go to the user's set default?

Comment: Default font in Excel 2003 is Arial 10 pt. To be safe you could create your form to look sharp with both Calibri and Arial. Check out this post (http://j-walk.com/ss/excel/tips/tip79.htm) for a quick VBA script that tests if a given font is installed. If you wanted to get fancy you could approximate the CSS font stack behavior using this script.

Comment: Super cool! That might be overkill for this project but it's neat to know that option exists. Thanks for the default font info and your other help!